# How can i solve the problem with undefined object after refreshing the page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So this is my ts file for my editor.First of all i am getting the product from the id that is given in the URL,and then i call the initializeUploader to initialise my photo ulpoader.First when i get in the page all is looking good,but after i refresh the page my product and uploader are not initialised anymore and then in the page nothing is shown...How can i make them to be initialised every time the page is refreshed so i don t get undefined objects.

This component is a child of a main component and the route to this component is given in the main one:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: AdminComponent},
{path: 'edit-product/:id', component: EditProductComponent, data: 
{breadcrumb: {alias: 'productDetails'}}},
{path: 'add-product', component: AddProductComponent, data: 
{breadcrumb: {alias: 'productDetails'}}},
];
```

Could the fact that my component is a child cause this?

```
        ngOnInit(): void {
           this.loadProduct();
           this.initializeUploader();
           console.log(this.product);

           }

       loadProduct() {                                                             this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!)
          .subscribe(product=> {
               this.product = product;
                this.bcService.set('@productDetails', product.name)
             }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                     });
               }

public fileOverBase(e: any): void {
this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
}

initializeUploader()
{
this.uploader = new FileUploader({
url: this.baseUrl + 'photos/'+this.product.id  + '/photos',
authToken: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
isHTML5: true,
allowedFileType: \['image'\],
removeAfterUpload: true,
autoUpload: false,
maxFileSize: 10 \* 1024 \* 1024 ,
});
}
}
```

I expect to get after the refresh my product initialised with the values that i get in the LoadProduct function and the same for my uploader

Comment: You should call to your function "initializeUploader" **inside** subscribe function (after the instruction "this.bcService.set(...)"). It's the only way you be sure that the variable this.product has value.

Comment: That seem to work,now i am getting just=>ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pictures')...it looks strange cause first i get the photos from the product good but then after refresh i am getting this...but still in the page the product images are shown correctly

Comment: @Eliseo i have checked and the pictures from my product are coming after the refresh but i am still getting the error that i have shown